# Mi objeto cae al vacio en vez de usar Lerp

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity, unity2d

estoy haciendo un juego estilo runner que no esta generado al azar y estoy intentando programar el Boss para que entre en escena y empiece la lucha final. El juego consiste en un astronauta (player) que siempre se queda en pantalla (asi que el, el fondo y la camera nunca se mueven, el jugador se mueve pero esta limitado con Clamp).

Todos los obstaculos vienen hacie el jugador y este tiene que evitarlos o dispararlos hasta que llega el ultimo que es el Boss. El Boss esta al final de la fila y tambien se mueve en el eje Z hacia el jugador y se para en cuanto toca un collider que se veria ya en la pantalla, para que el Boss no se mueva mas hacia la izquierda y comience la lucha.

Despues de que se pare quiero que el Boss se mueva de arriba a abajo y de abajo arriba con funciones Lerp. Este es el codigo:

The code looks like this:

```
public class BossController : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;
public float health;
public Animator anim;
public Transform startMarker;
public Transform endMarker;

private Rigidbody rb;
private HUDController hud;
private bool startIntro = false;

private float startTime;
private float journeyLength;

void Start () {
    startTime = Time.time;
    journeyLength = Vector3.Distance (startMarker.position, endMarker.position);

    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    rb.velocity = transform.forward * -speed;

}

void Update(){

    if (startIntro) {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        Fight ();
    }
}

 void Fight(){

    float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
    float fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;

    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startMarker.position, endMarker.position, fracJourney);
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(endMarker.position, startMarker.position, fracJourney);

}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("bossEntry")) {
        startIntro = true;
        //anim.SetTrigger ("quad"); 
    }
}

}
```

La estructura es un Empty que contiene el mesh, el punto de salida y el punto final para el Lerp. Solo el Empty (parent) tiene un Rigidbody (bueno dos) que son trigger.

[image]
[image]

Ayuda? Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Trata de remover el rigidbody o activarle "Is Kinematic" en las opciones del rigidbody, a veces los rigidbodies ponenp roblema por moverlos en el update mediante transform.position, para mover un rigidbody es mejor usar regidbody.addforce().